# Would text-substitution and text-replacement tags be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I propose creating the ‘text-replacement’ tag for iOS (and perhaps synonym ‘text-substitution’, the OS X term for the same thing, to it)?

If you search for `NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems`, you'll see that there's plenty of posts on the topic already!

Comment: Why would this tag be helpful?

Comment: Personally, I did about four searches for various phrasings of ‘text substitution’, before posting a question myself; and after doing so, I'm *still* not at all convinced that nobody's asked it before. There's dozens of posts on the topic, some duplicates of eachother, and it seems to me they'd be useful centralized.